# asp.net c# Web Forms send email using outlook 365

Tags: asp.net, email, office365, send

this was my code for my local machine before my company switched to outlook 365:
SmtpClient SMTP Client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMailServer"]);
smtpClient.Send(message);

Since the outlook was changed, I google and find this code, however it does not work giving error code "Failed to send email" "General failure".
Please help me to resolve this issue
here is a new code:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredentmailial("email address", "network password");
                client.Port = 25; // You can use Port 25 if 587 is blocked (mine is!)
                client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                //client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";
                client.Send(message);
```

Thank you very much.
Vitaly.

Comment: Set `EnableSsl` property to `false` and uncomment this `//client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;` line. As you say you don't use **Port 587**. 587 is SSL port

Comment: But it is still not working. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Unreliable SMTP is not allowed with office365. check this link to send mail using MS Graph API - https://medium.com/medialesson/how-to-send-emails-in-net-with-the-microsoft-graph-a97b57430bbd.
sample - https://github.com/GrillPhil/GraphEmailSample

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to send the email using HOST **smtp.office365.com**

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@domain.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@domain.com", "To Name");
string fromPassword = "Your_email_password";
string subject = "Test Subject";
string body = "Test Message";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.office365.com",
    Port = 25, //Recommended port is 587
    EnableSsl = false,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Please check that is your **port 25** is blocked by OS or not.
[image]